# Joining 2 tables on multiple OR conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

What I want to accomplish:
I want to join 2 tables on urls. But one table has url formats that are a bit different from the other. As they are the only common denominator between the two tables, (no unique id's to join on) I have to use wildcards to match the url's.

For example one table has formats like these: 'www.url.com', 'url.com.', 'abc.def.url.com' while another table has format 'url.com'
So in order to match I need to do something like

```
LEFT JOIN t1
ON t1.url = '%.'||t2.url OR t1.url= t2.url||'.' OR etc...
```

Is this the right way to approach this?

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very strict constraint as you are joining on URLs. url.com should match url.com and www.url.com should match url.com but www.dummyurl.com shouldnt match www.myurl.com. Your original query is fine and is the right way to approach the problem.

To avoid overmatching, would recommend using this

```
select * from t1 inner join t2
on t1.url like '%.'||t2.url or t1.url = t2.url
```

*I have used inner join to avoid NULL matching*       [Here's a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/18a03/2)

This assumes that t2.url will be at the end of t1.uel after a period or both strictly match. Try running this and see if you get your anticipated results

Comment: I am getting 10328 entries and  4239 unique entries. Not bad though. Do you think I'll be able to get rid of the duplicates? @Shreyas Chavan

Comment: When I join on `t1.url like '%.'||t2.url or t1.url = t2.url` and there is url.com and asdf.url.com in t2.url and the url in t1.url I want to match is asdf.url.com, it will give me 2 entries including both url.com and asdf.url.com. I guess this is harder to prevent from happening.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately you will always have corner cases like these. There is no overarching solution as such. This solution will give you a decent output. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, can you use CONTAINS()?

```
LEFT JOIN t1
ON CONTAINS(t1.url, t2.url)
```

Edit: Well, seems that PostGRE doesn't support CONTAINS.

Try using position() function. It returns 0 if the substring is not found

```
ON position(t2.url in t1.url) <> 0
```

Comment: Just tried it but didn't work. Either it doesn't work on PostgreSQL or permission is denied per error message.

Comment: I tried applying the updated code but I ran into two problems. First, lots and lots of duplicates and second, matching too much. For instance, I don't want www.myurl.com  to match www.dummyurl.com.